# Unable to Insert Date into Data Extension via SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

**The Problem**

I am trying to convert a date-time field that is retrieved from a `WSProxy` call previously. The date-time is provided to me in the format of `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss`, trying to insert this value into a data extension where the field type is of type `Date` will fail but will as expected successfully insert into `Text` fields.

When I test and try to insert `Date.now()` into a `Date` data extension field, it works without issue. A `Date.now()` value is also in milliseconds (epoch).

Because of this; I thought that I could simply use `Date.parse(string)` which will convert a date-time string into its respective milliseconds' value (epoch). Unfortunately, this seems to fail.

**My Sample Code**

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

  var myDE = DataExtension.Init("my_test_de");
  var status = "complete"; // string
  var start_time = Date.now(); // EPOCHmilliseconds
  var complete_time = "2022-05-19T07:28:28.397" // string ISO
  var date_complete_time = Date.parse(complete_time); // converts ISOstring to EPOCH

  myDE.Rows.Add({Status: status, StartTime: start_time, CompleteTime: complete_time, CompleteTimeDate: date_complete_time});
</script>
```

**The Question**: How do I parse and insert an ISO Date-Time field retrieved in SSJS so that it will be accepted as input for a `Date` Field in my Data Extension?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed the date field needs to be in ISO 8601; however your example has it statically coded, so I am assuming that you got the date-time from a data extension or as a result of a SOAP API call.

I'm not sure if this is a bug with the SSJS or if it's intended given the version of SSJS that's used. When retrieving dates via API, most of the time I end up with an array of objects.

```
var array = [{"Status":1,"StatusMessage":"Complete","StartTime":"2022-05-19T07:28:01.561","CompletedTime":"2022-05-19T07:28:28.397"}, {"Status":1,"StatusMessage":"Complete","StartTime":"2022-05-19T07:28:01.561","CompletedTime":"2022-05-19T07:28:28.397"}]
```

I iterate through the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var status = array[i].Status;
        var status_message = array[i].StatusMessage;
        var start_time = array[i].StartTime;
        var completed_time = array[i].CompletedTime;
    }
```

Now there is a problem here; `start_time` and `completed_time` were both provided by the API in ISO format, however, when doing this assignment, SSJS will change it to from: `2022-05-19T07:28:01.561` to: `5/19/2022 7:28:01 AM`. I am not sure why this happens but you can verify that it does by trying to insert either into a `Text` attributed field in a data extension.

The ONLY way I could find to persis milliseconds and preserve the original integrity of the date-time is to do the following:

```
        var completed_time = Stringify(history[n].CompletedTime);
        completed_time = completed_time.replace(/[\"\']/gi, "");
```

`Stringify` in this case will encapsulate the entire result for `CompletedTime` in double-quotes; thus preserving the ISO format. However, it's not encapsulated in double-quotes so we do a `replace to remove the double-quotes.

The resulting value for `completed_time` will be entered in ISO format into a `Text` attribute in a DE and will also be accepted into a `Date` attribute in a DE.

Alternatively, you can write your own `toISOString` function but unfortunately when you do `new Date(string)`, the milliseconds are lost.